# Bulk load data conversion error while importing DATETIME data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I found a few posts on this topic on StackOverflow, but none seem to solve my problem.

I am trying to set up bulk imports for SQL Server 2008 Express, and it is failing to import `datetime` values.  The issue seems so basic that I must be missing something very simple, and I'm hoping someone else can catch the problem.

### The Problem

I am importing into this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BulkTest](
    [ReportDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

This is my format file (BulkTest.fmt):

```
10.0
1
1       SQLDATETIME   0       0       "\r\n"   1     ReportDate                                 ""
```

This is the data being imported (BulkTest.tab):

```
ReportDate
2010-12-31
2011-01-31
```

This is the import statement:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.BulkTest
FROM 'Q:\...\BulkTest.tab'
WITH (
    CHECK_CONSTRAINTS,
    TABLOCK,
    FORMATFILE='Q:\...\BulkTest.fmt',
    FIRSTROW=1,
    DATAFILETYPE='char'
    );
```

These are the errors:

```
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (ReportDate).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (ReportDate).
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
```

### I Have Tried

- Changing the date format, including `12/31/2010`, `31/12/2010`, `20101231`, `2010-12-31 00:00:00`, and various other formats.
- Adding/removing/changing bulk insert statement options `DATAFILETYPE`, `TABLOCK`, `CHECK_CONSTRAINTS`.
- Changing the delimiter and the field size in the format file (though per MSDN the field size should not matter).
- Running `SET DATEFORMAT ymd`.
- Checking the imported file with hex editor to make sure that it really does contain 8-bit chars and not unicode; it contains exactly what is shown in ASCII format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is the format that works in my code:

```
08/17/2000 16:32:32
```

The producer happens to be .NET, `ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)`.

Comment: This format works for me pretty much in all cases except for the case described above.  I am suspecting that this may be a problem not related to date format specifically, but rather has to do with the way I am importing the dates (e.g. maybe truncating the date somewhere, or doing something else without realizing it).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a format file for this? What happens when you don't use it?

```
BULK INSERT dbo.BulkTest
FROM 'Q:\...\BulkTest.tab'
WITH (
    CHECK_CONSTRAINTS,
    TABLOCK,
    FIRSTROW=1,
    DATAFILETYPE='char',
    ROWTERMINATOR='\r\n'
);
```

Comment: This is a simplified case of a problem that I was having with a bulk insert where I did need a format file (30 columns in the table, only 15 columns in the imported data and some of them are out of order).  For this post, I reduced the problem to the simplest case that produces the same error.

Comment: Interesting, removing the format file still causes the same problem.

Comment: What is the collation of the server/database? What happens if you leave out the CHECK_CONSTRAINTS and DATAFILETYPE options?

Comment: Collation is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.  I tried adding/removing the `WITH` options, including CHECK_CONSTRAINTS and DATAFILETYPE, and tried various combinations of them, and it still produces the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm late to the party but I hope this can help some other poor soul.

Anyway I discovered the same error when using the format file.

Instead of type **SQLDATE** I used **SQLCHAR** and the length.

2015-01-01 = length 10

> 11.0
>
> 1
>
> 1       SQLCHAR             0       10      "\r\n"   1     my_date  ""